# Comparator for Priority Queue[C++]

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

I am trying to understand what my comparator should return for a Priority Queue of vectors where I want a min-heap based on third element.

On searching , I found out that the comparator looks like :

```
bool operator()(vector<int>a, vector<int> b)
{
return a[2]>b[2];
}
```

Why not `a[2]<b[2]`?

Comment: `std::priority_queue` returns the maximum element first. That's just the way it's defined.

Comment: And this comparator will make `priority_queue` put the minimum element on top

Comment: Use const references to vector instead of passing by value, you do not want to copy them every time you compare

Comment: cppreference has a really good explanation of how the comparator should look like and why. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @flowit was not able to comprehend it at first but after jotting down a few examples got to understand what it really meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A max heap is a vector or binary tree where the data contained in each node is greater than or equal to that of its children, so the leaves have the smallest values in the queue. Internally, the priority queue is represented as a max heap and sorted so that nodes with the largest value can be accessed first. If you wanted to sort elements `a[2]<b[2]`, you can overwrite the comparator.